# AcceptButton and CancelButton for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, acceptbutton

Where are the Form Properties for the AcceptButton and CancelButton for Visual Studio 2010? I'd like to set my btnClose as CancelButton and I'd like to set my btnEnter as my AcceptButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties you are talking about are AcceptButton and CancelButton on the Form.

Make sure you select the Form in the form designer, and then look in the property panel.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, indeed. For whatever reason I could not see it there in the first place. Alas there on the Form is the AcceptButton. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your property panel is orgranized by category. If so, look under the "misc" category

Comment: I will check to see if that is the case. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a windows form in VS 2010? Then you would make two buttons and associate actions in the code behind. Make two buttons, btnCancel and btnEnter and to generate codebehind simply double click the buttons in UI and provide the code.

Code for cancel button is something like:

```
void btnCancel_Close(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    this.close();
}
```

Comment: I thought there was a way to simply type btnClose and set the CancelButton within control properties of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, then in the designer make sure you have the Form selected. In the Properties Window, the combo box should see something like

**Form1** System.Windows.Forms.Form

Then under the Misc Grouping, you should see the `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` properties that you can set to whatever buttons are on your form. Again, make sure the form is the selected component in the designer window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the walk through. I'll be sure to have the form selected from now on.